# Common login script

Tags: linux, logging, shell

Few weeks ago I thought it would be a good idea to write a script which should send me an email whenever some user would log in into my server.

So I came to a perfectly working script `notifyLogin.sh`, then I decided to call it from each user's  `.bash_login` script.

So long so good but today I discovered that someone could log in in my server using `ssh` client `-t` option selecting thus an available shell. For example:

```
ssh user@myserver -t sh
```

This way, `.bash_login` do not execute, neither `/etc/profile`.

My question is: Is there any "universal" (that means that id does not matter which shell is being used) script that executes whenever a user log in?

Comment: No, any global script that gets run is ran by the shell or process being started.  Different shells (may) use different files. A better way to achieve what you are trying to do would be to configure your system so that logins are logged to your log files.  You then act on those log entries by having a script or program monitor those files and either alerting or running another script/program when those log entries are found.

Comment: @yoonix This logins are already being registered and I can check them using `last` tool, am I wrong?

Comment: You're not wrong, but you running last and looking for new entries repeatedly does not equate to 'sending an email when a user logs in.'  It can work but it's far less efficient IMO.  Instead of running one script that continuously watches you're going to run that command repeatedly even if nobody new has logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to use syslog and redirect the message to email:

- [Mail Output Module (ommail) for rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/ommail.html)
- [smtp() driver in syslog-ng](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.4-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-v3.4-guide-admin/html/configuring-destinations-smtp.html)

Another way is to use a log parser like [SEC](http://simple-evcorr.sourceforge.net/) or [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use pam. Stolen from [page found in google](http://blog.th-neumeier.de/2011/02/send-email-on-ssh-login-using-pam/):

```
session optional pam_exec.so /path/to/your/script/or/executable
```

For details see [pam_exec(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_exec) man page. The advantage is that you don't need to parse the logs to do it - it uses standard mechanism for plugging-in sessions. Depending on where you put it you can use it to send whenever user creates a new session or only when it connects via SSH.

Answer (score 1):

an alternative: you may run a filtering of secure log in a background to extract interesting events, like:

```
tail -n 0 -f /var/log/secure | grep --line-buffered "sshd:session): session opened" > /var/log/sec-filtered
```

and have a periodic task that checks for size of filtered output file to send it be e-mail and restart filtering on secure log.